# How can I make Facebook login as Android library and made the library available other Android application

Tags: android, facebook

I'm new to Android Studio and gradle build system. I try to create an Android library for Facebook login through the app and try to import the library in to the sample Android application. But it is not work.

My library consist of Android manifest.xml, layout xml, gradle and Activity.

I defined the MainActivity and facebookActivity in library Manifest file. And I did the initialization of Facebook SDK in the library itself and the login button in to the layout xml file. And I add the library as dependency in to the sample app.

In sample app i try to call the activities from the library. So that in sample app manifest file i define the activity that used in the library manifest file and call the activity by creating an intent in sample app. But it doesn't work.
How can i make this possible?

This  is my library Manifest File. The package name is `com.fb.agazeadmin.fblogin`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.fb.agazeadmin.fblogin">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"     android:value="964354013632944"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges=
            "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
</application>
</manifest>
```

This is my sample app Manifest file. Package name of sample App is `com.fb.agazeadmin.hwapplication`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.fb.agazeadmin.hwapplication">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <!--activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity-->
    <activity android:name="com.fb.agazeadmin.fblogin.LoginActivity" />



</application>

</manifest>

    [This is my project Structure][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 File -> Project structure -> Modules
```

There you add projects as libraries in android studio

Follow **method two here**: https://github.com/MagicMicky/FreemiumLibrary/wiki/Import-the-library-in-Android-Studio

Comment: I can able to add the library in to my application .I add the library as .aar file into the sample application.My aim is to bring the facebook login in the library able to sync with the sample app.The facebook login button is did in the library .Firt i created the library as android app later it works after that i converted in to library.And this library is i try to import to an android sample app .So that i copy the .aar file from the library and paste in the libs folder in sample app.

Comment: you have:- compile project(':<your-library-project>') in your gradle file? If you have that , you can use the library as whats in the library... The usage of the library depends on the library itself!